# Am I able to get more technical help here on a gaming question I have on Arqade SE?

Tags: discussion, support

I have a problem with the display driver or something for one of my old games and I cant seem to get an answer for it. it is indeed a very technical question so if I post it here would you guys be able to give me a heads up on it or any advise what so ever to get it to work... its also to do with compatibility with windows 8/8.1. [Heres the link](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/172321/no-suitable-display-mode-found-error-for-dawn-of-war-dow-winter-assault):

Thanks in advance for any or all input into this, its one of my favourite PC game series

PS I also had a bounty on this question which was subsequently squandered so I am reluctant to post another haha

Answer (score 3):

Well, we would need more information about your PC. But yes, technical support type questions are allowed here, as long as they follow the rules, and show that you have tried something already, and tried researching *why* it's not working.

As for the actual move, I don't know how the mods there would act, but you could try editing in any more possible information into the question, ping someone in the [Root Access](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) chat room, then if we like it, ask mods on Arquade to migrate over to here.